# Open workbooks based on a list and run a specific macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to open all of the workbooks in this range and run their macros. The idea is to open the first workbook, run the macro, and then close it before moving on to the next. The name of the macro is the same across all workbooks. I'm running the code and I'm getting (subscript out of range) error. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub files_export()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim startsheet As Worksheet
Set startsheet = wb.Worksheets("Start")
    
Dim linkrange As Range
Set linkrange = startsheet.Range("C4:C21") 
    
    Dim y As String
    Dim c As Range
    
    For Each c In linkrange
        If c.Value <> "" Then
           y = c.Value
           Workbooks.Open (y)
           Workbooks(y).Application.Run ("macro1")
           Workbooks.close (y)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Not the issue here, but don't use parenthesis when calling functions/subs without the using the returned value nor using the keyword `Call` like you did here : `Workbooks.Open (y)` and here : `Workbooks.close (y)`.

Comment: Put a break point in the loop and check your paths (the y value). Is is a correct path? Is the Excel workbooks correctly opening? Note that if y is a full qualified path, you won't be able to access it by `Workbooks(y)` even if the workbook opens, since it will be referenced by its filename without drive and folder.

Comment: One solution would be to get the workbook's variable returned by the Open function and use it to run the macro and then close the file.

Comment: The workbook is open as it should be, and y is the full path to the workbook.  My issue I think is defining the macro correctly. @VincentG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Run Macro In Another Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilesExport()

    Const dName As String = "Start"
    Const FilePathsRangeAddress As String = "C4:C21"
    Const ModuleName As String = "" ' or e.g. "Module1"
    Const MacroName As String = "Macro1"

    Dim ModName As String: ModName = ModuleName
    If Len(ModName) > 0 Then ModName = ModName & "."

    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    Dim fprg As Range: Set fprg = dws.Range(FilePathsRangeAddress)
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim swbPath As String
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sMacroString As String
    
    For Each sCell In fprg.Cells
        swbPath = CStr(sCell.Value)
        If Len(swbPath) > 0 Then
           If Len(Dir(swbPath)) > 0 Then
               Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbPath)
               sMacroString = "'" & swb.Name & "'!" & ModName & MacroName
               swb.Application.Run sMacroString
               swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' maybe 'True' ?
           End If
        End If
    Next sCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try replacing of:

```
Workbooks(y).Application.Run ("macro1")
```

with:

```
Application.Run y & "!.macro1"
```

Note1: `macro1` should exist in a standard module.

Note2: using the workbook full name will make the `y` workbook opening, if not already open... You can use the workbook `Name`, extracting it from the full name, but this will work only if the workbook in discussion is open (like in your case).

Comment: Macro is correctly defined, but it is not running due to error 1004 macros may not be enabled. @FaneDuru

Comment: @steven You mentioned "subscript out of range" as error, not what you say now. Is this the new error after running the above suggestion? If so, you have to place the folder(s), where the workbooks to be open exist, in Excel `Trusted Locations`. Otherwise, they are opened by code with macros disabled. I can supply a piece of code doing this automatically, but you (the user running the code) must be the folder 'Owner`. In fact I can do that programmatically, too. if the user is an administrator... Only once, when needed.

Comment: But, for now, please do it manually (`Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Settings... - Trusted Locations` and `Add new location`, then test the code again.

Comment: @steven Didn't you find some time to apply the above suggestion? If applied, didn't it solve the problem?

Comment: This is the new error after running the new suggestions. I tried to do it manually as you suggested but I am not the folder owner. So the same issue persist. @FaneDuru

Comment: @steven You are not, but you know how to play with the folder security to become its Owner? Right click on the folder, then choose the `Security` tab. `Advanced security` and click 'Change` after the existing `Owner:`. Then, write your user name and press `Check names`. If you spelled it correctly it should be transforming in a kind of link. Now press OK.

Comment: I believe the problem is that, for some reason, the macro name contains the entire filepath rather than the macro's name. @FaneDuru

Comment: @steven How to contain only the full file name if it is concatenated with `"!.macro1"`. **Ups**, I forget a not necessary parenthesis. Please, **delete the ending one**... I will also adapt the code... Adapted!

Comment: The macro name appears at the end of the filepath. However, it recognizes the entire filepath and macro name as one. I suppose having y open as a filepath isn't a good idea.

Comment: @steven it shouldn't matter. Like I said, it works, it will even open the workbook if not open already. I tried it many times... Did you delete the ending parenthesis which is a mistake? If you thought I forgot the first one and you put it there, **please delete both of them**. Instead of the first one, place a space (" ")... If you use the argument(s) between parenthesis you have to use `Call` before it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240604/discussion-between-steven-and-faneduru).

Comment: One last idea: Please, move/copy one of the workbooks to the path of the workbook where the code runs, adapt the path in the testing Sub and try running it. Does it work?

Comment: And you did  not confirmed that the macro is in a standard module...